# Changing font for Hydrogen Atom Code Inspector

Tags: atom-editor, hydrogen

How do I change the font (and font size) for the Code Inspector pane (accessible from the Command Palette 'Hydrogen: Toggle Inspector')?

Asking mainly because the font size is a tad too small for me when I pull up the Inspector pane.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Hydrogen version 1.22.0 you can configure the font size for the output and side panels (including the inspector) inside the Hydrogen settings.

For older versions you need to customize the user style sheet of Atom.